# Algorithm for Adding new line for overflowing string

Tags: php

For example I have a string like below

```
$str = "What does the fox say to the elephant"
```

And I have the character limit per line is 10.

I want to add New line (\n) to the end of the word after 10 char.And the result output should be like

```
"What does the\n fox say to the\n elephant"
```

I tried something like below.

```
$str = "What does the fox say to the elephant"
echo funk($str);

function funk($s)
{

$s= explode(" ",$s);
foreach($s as $so)
{
$count += strlen($so);

if($count > 10)
{
$newstr = "$so/n ";
}
else
{
$newstr  = "$so";
}

}

}
```

Comment: `wordwrap()` does exactly what you need, just that it breaks the line before the word and not after.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's wordwrap function is what you need:

```
<?php
$text = "A very long woooooooooooooooooord. and something";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 8, "\n", false);

echo "$newtext\n";
```

Changing the final param (currently false) will determine whether strings are split at whitespace only or during any point during the string.

From the PHP Manual - http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php